# How to use XML and XML Schemas with C#

Tags: c#, xml

HI,

I want to keep the Outlook contacts in an XML file. And I want to compare, merge and resolve conflicts of this XML file with another XML file which may have same attributes ?
Also I want to know when a particular node is editied/newly added ? How we can achieve this in XML using C# 3.5 ? Should I use any XML Schemas ? How this is possible ?

Also please let me know using which one is faster - a XML file or a SQLite ?

Comment: The params of your question are not well defined (what are the rules for your merge going to be?) but I can tell you SQLite will almost certainly be "faster", but for merging and portability xml might be better. Situational basically.

Comment: I'd consider SQL Server Express over SQLite. And which is better will depend in part on your experience. XML may seem foreign to you at first and maybe Relational will seem simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML, there are various books on LINQ to XML, please refer them.

for small data XML should be fast and effective way to go like configuration data, etc.
for large data SQLite is the way to go.